# Dynamic elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium

In the GUI, there is a drop down which has few values. When we select each value, the new elements appear. The elements in Drop down is Fund-Specific and Plan-specific. If i select Fund, then i get the elements related to fund like fund number, amount etc. if i select plan, then i get plan name, plan number, amount. i use keyword driven framework. How do i handle this dynamic generated elements? Please help with the resolution.
This is the case in one page. i have like this in many pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know answer, You are passing value that is your Actual Test data and You already know expected data that is dynamic element or dynamic value. I would definitely write switch statement that verify what is expected data should be on based actual passing value like passing fund and switch statement take that fund keyword and wait for element to come on page.

This piece of code will wait for element to

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfElementLocated(by));

I will advised add some code in comment to provide more accurate answer.

Comment: so i have this code for the different actions available.             public void perform() {
  WebElement webElement;
  switch(this.action){
  case "EnterText" :
   System.out.println("EnterText");
   webElement = findObject();
   webElement.sendKeys(this.value);
   }
   break;
  case "Click" :
   System.out.println("Click");
   webElement = findObject();
   webElement.click();
   break;
  case "Select":
   System.out.println("Select");
   webElement = findObject();
   Select select = new Select(webElement);
   select.selectByVisibleText(this.value);
      break;

Comment: In the above code i need to add logic specific to Fund and Plan in the select statement.?

Comment: Yes You need add logic, You don't know when you dynamic value will come on page, It can be in 2sec or in 20 min, You need to add expectation condition that i posted above, It wait for certain time that you can decide and it will wait.

Comment: Yes, You need to add value that will decide what do. If you are passing fund than switch function got to fund function and check value you are expecting.